Cannot remove the event listener
I'm trying to add a mousemove event when mousedown and remove it when mouseup, it adds the move event but it doesn't get removed. It successfully triggers the mouseup event but don't remove the mousemove.
 zoomDiv.addEventListener("mousedown", ()=>{
            console.log("mousedown");
            zoomDiv.addEventListener("mousemove", e => mouseDown(e))
        })
        zoomDiv.addEventListener("mouseup", ()=>{
            console.log("mouseup")
            zoomDiv.removeEventListener("mousemove", e => mouseDown(e))
        })

I'm trying to add a mousemove event when mousedown and remove it when mouseup, it adds the move event but don't remove it. It succesfuly triggers the mouseup event but don't remove the mousemove.

You need to provide removeEventListener with the exact same function reference, as you used when you added the listener. You are using e => mouseDown(e) in two places - which will create a function that does the same thing each time, but it will not be the same function. You need to create the function beforehand, and store the reference to it into a variable.

Sounds like an X/Y problem

Instead of adding and removing those mousemove handlers (and presumably keeping on doing that?), it would probably make more sense to leave the mousemove handler in place - and then simply determine if a button was pressed, inside the handler function. The mousemove handler gets a MouseEvent instance passed in, and that has properties such as button/buttons, that will help you determine this.

Sounds like you really want drag events - Drag and drop API

I realy didn't know about drag events, thanks

@samet Please either share your solution or delete the question

I've used @Magmatic's way to solve the problem, and chose it as the accepted answer.

Technically the function you are trying to remove is a different function. Instead, you need to set your function to a variable, then remove that same variable, something like this: (untested)
let mouseMoveFunction = (e) => {
  console.log("mouseMoveFunction");
  mouseDownFunction(e)
}

let mouseDownFunction = (e) => {
  console.log("mouseDownFunction");
  zoomDiv.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveFunction)
}

let mouseUpFunction = (e) => {
  console.log("mouseUpFunction")
  zoomDiv.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveFunction)
}

zoomDiv.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownFunction)
zoomDiv.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpFunction)

Also, keep in mind that after the mouse is down and moving, each pixel it moves, it will add another event listener that will call itself to add another listener. This is exponential growth, and pretty soon there will be hundreds or thousands of listeners added. But this might be slightly out of the scope of your original question.
